# Linux : Will stat access Hard Disk for its operation

Tags: c++, c, linux, io, filesystems

We need check whether **stat()** call will **access Hard disk** during its operation?

i coulnt find answer for above question.

can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `stat(2)` identifies the file with a pathname, the system has no option but to query the filesystem for the information.

I suppose the information could happen to be in a cache, so actually hitting the disk might not happen for a particular call, but generally the system will need to perform I/O.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. is there any tool on linux to check this?